# LoF/LoT: Font change of caption prefix

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, koma-script

I would like to change the font of the "caption prefix" of the list of figure and list of tables from serif to `\textbf` and **sans-serif** (see figure for details). Is there a `KOMA`-Script work-around or do I need the `tocloft` package (...or something else)?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mwe}

  \begin{document}
    \chapter{MWE}
    \blindtext

    \begin{figure}
    \caption {MWE figure for detail information}
    \end{figure}
    \blindtext

    %==== BACK MATTER ====
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage

  \end{document}
```

I am grateful for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` command as shown in the follwing MWE:

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrreprt}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\sffamily\bfseries]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\sffamily\bfseries]{tocline}{table}

  \begin{document}
  \chapter{MWE}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption {MWE figure for detail information}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
    \caption {MWE table for detail information}
    \end{table}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
   \end{document}
```

This will leave the prefix in the captions unchanged and only affects the prefixes and numbers in the `listoffigures` and `listoftables`.

[image]